# SPI complete callback handler

Tags: c, linux, kernel, spi

I am writing a SPI driver for linux. Some relevant documents are http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/spi/spi-summary and http://ww2.cs.fsu.edu/~rosentha/linux/2.6.26.5/docs/DocBook/kernel-api/ch25.html.

Most of the time the transfers are performed successfully and my completion callback is called. When I access the messages's `status` I always see zero (indicating). The `actual_length` is 112 (my transfer length) as desired.

However, after some time it might happen that I get a callback with `actual_length == 0`. All subsequent calls even have `actual_length == 224` . After closing the spi device, the callback is then still getting called with message lengths rising quickly (each call, it's increased by 112), although I didn't call `spi_async` anymore.

Can anybody provide a hint what could cause this behaviour?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the reason was a threading issue: We overwrote the spi_message object before the last transfer was completed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expertise but if you are using dma etc., there is maybe cache coherency problem.